# What is openInfoWindowHtml and GPolygon in google maps V3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
   var polygon = new GPolygon(polylines[0],"#FFFFFF", 1, 1.0, color,opacity);

  polygon.hid = this.id;
  polygon.heat = this.heat;

   google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'click', function(point) {

    HoodsUnselect(active_hood_id);
    active_hood_id = polygon.hid;
polygon.setOptions({fillColor: '#2948e4', fillOpacity: 0.50 });
  //polygon.setFillStyle( { color:'#2948e4',opacity:'0.50' } );

    if (point) {
      map.openInfoWindowHtml(point, the_list);  // open info window where user clicked

    } else {
       map.openInfoWindowHtml(polygon.getBounds().getCenter(), the_list);  // open info window at the center of polygon
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In addition to [Tony's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268099/what-is-openinfowindowhtml-and-gpolygon-in-google-maps-v3/3268240#3268240), there is no `openInfoWindowHtml()` method in the v3 API. You'd have to create an [`InfoWindow`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#InfoWindows) object, on which you can call the `open()` or `close()` methods. You'd normally want just one `InfoWindow` object if you want just one visible at the same time:

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

google.maps.event.addListener(yourOverlay, 'click', function () {
   infoWindow.setContent('Some info on yourOverlay');
   infoWindow.open(map);
});
```

The main difference between the v2 API and v3 API when it comes to Info Windows is the fact that in the v3 API you can have more than one Info Window open at the same time. This was not possible in the v2 API. To have multiple Info Windows open, you'd want to create multiple `InfoWindow` objects, and not just one for all the markers (overlays).

As for the polygons, this is how to create a polygon in the v3 API (borrowed from the example [mentioned by @Tony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268099/what-is-openinfowindowhtml-and-gpolygon-in-google-maps-v3/3268240#3268240)):

```
var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
  paths: [
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
    new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
    new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.75737)
  ],
  strokeColor: "#FF0000",
  strokeOpacity: 0.8,
  strokeWeight: 3,
  fillColor: "#FF0000",
  fillOpacity: 0.35
});

bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
```

Comment: There should be a problem in your code, I am using v3 and infoWindow.open gets two parameters : `infoWindow.open = function(a,b){this.set("anchor",b);this.set("map",a)}`

Comment: @Mehdi Karamosly: The second argument is optional. If passed, it's the marker at which the info window will pop up. If not specified, it will just appear at some default position (top-left). (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows#open)

Answer (score 3):

The v3 equivalent of GPolyline is [Polyline](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Polyline) and GPolygon is [Polygon](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Polygon).  Both of these have click events that you can listen for.

Even better, Google provides [Polyline examples](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Polylines) and [Polygon examples](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Polygons), including [one that listens for clicks and opens an infowindow](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-arrays.html).